# Como retornar um DataReader C#

Tags: c#

*Sei que estou fazendo da maneira errada.*

Porém gostaria de saber se é possível dentro do que estou tentando retornar um dataReader.

Veja, eu criei um classe chamada cliente que tem o método "BuscarCliente" a mesma possuí a classe de conexão junto, código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;
using System.Collections;

namespace ProgramaGE
{
    class Clientes
    {
        static string serverName = "localhost";
        static string port = "5432";
        static string userName = "postgres";
        static string password = "adm";
        static string databaseName = "GE";
        NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
        string ConnString = null;

        public Clientes()
        {
            ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                       serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

        }

        public bool InserirCliente(ArrayList p_arr)
        { 
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdInserir = String.Format("INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, ENDERECO, CIDADE, EMAIL, TELEFONE) VALUES (@NOME, @ENDERECO, @CIDADE, @EMAIL, @TELEFONE)");
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@NOME", p_arr[0]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ENDERECO", p_arr[1]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@CIDADE", p_arr[2]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@EMAIL", p_arr[3]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@TELEFONE", p_arr[4]));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        public int UltimoRegistroCliente()
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdLast = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES ORDER BY ID_CLIENTE DESC LIMIT 1;");

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdLast, conn))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }
        }

        public NpgsqlDataReader BuscarCliente(ArrayList p_arr)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE id_cliente = @ID");
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(p_arr[0])));

                    NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        p_arr[1] = reader[0].ToString(); //txt.Text que vou passar e coluna que vou trazer dao db
                        p_arr[2] = reader[1].ToString();
                        p_arr[3] = reader[2].ToString();
                        p_arr[4] = reader[3].ToString();
                        p_arr[5] = reader[4].ToString();
                        p_arr[6] = reader[5].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {                
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O método eu **estou fazendo igual o de inserir**, utilizei desta forma no botão de buscar:

```
 private void btnBuscarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clientes buscar = new Clientes();
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

            arr.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtBuscarCliente.Text));
            arr.Add(txtId.Text);
            arr.Add(txtNomeCliente.Text);
            arr.Add(txtEndereco.Text);
            arr.Add(txtCidade.Text);
            arr.Add(txtEmail.Text);
            arr.Add(txtTelefone.Text);

            buscar.BuscarCliente(arr)
        }
```

Não da erro nenhum, só quero saber se isso que estou fazendo `é possível` caso sim, como posso terminar de implementar.

Obrigado!

Comment: No, você consegue acessar o seu txtId.Text no BuscarCliente ?

Comment: Creio que não, só quando passo pelo Array.

Comment: Só se for na implementação do botão, ai consigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olha, não vejo como você poderia fazer isto de forma segura. Se você usar o `using`, o `DataReader` estará fechado, se não usar o `using`, a conexão ficará aberta até que alguém feche a mesma.

Uma alternativa, é passa uma `Action<​Db​Data​Reader>` e nela fazer todas as operações necessárias.

```
public static List<Cliente> BuscarCliente(int id, Function<NpgsqlDataReader, Cliente> callback) 
{
    var clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE id_cliente = @ID");
        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));
            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var cliente = callback(reader);
                    clientes.Add(cliente);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return clientes;
}

public static Main()
{
    var idExterno = Guid.NewGuid();
    BuscarCliente(123, (reader) => {
        var cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.IdExterno = idExterno;
        cliente.Prop1 = reader[0].ToString();
        cliente.Prop2 = reader[1].ToString();
        cliente.Prop3 = reader[2].ToString();
        cliente.Prop4 = reader[3].ToString();
        cliente.Prop5 = reader[4].ToString();
        cliente.Prop6 = reader[5].ToString();
        return cliente;
    });
}
```

Você inclusive pode tornar o método acima mais genérico, lendo as colunas do cabeçalho do `DbDataReader`, montando o retorno de forma dinamica, etc.

Ao meu ver, esta abordagem está longe do Recomendado. Se puder, aconselho que utilize pelo menos o `Dapper`, ou melhor ainda `Dapper + Dommel`.

**EDIT**

No seu caso em especifico, o código abaixo deve bastar.:

```
public void BuscarCliente(int id, Action<NpgsqlDataReader> callback) 
{
    using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE id_cliente = @ID");
        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));
            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    callback(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnBuscarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(txtBuscarCliente.Text);
    BuscarCliente(id, (reader) => {
        txtId.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        txtNomeCliente.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        txtEndereco.Text = reader[2].ToString();
        txtCidade.Text = reader[3].ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = reader[4].ToString();
        txtTelefone.Text = reader[5].ToString();
    });
}
```

Comment: Entendi então, vou dar um testada no que postou, mas acredito que a solução mais `simples != recomendada` é implementar diretamente no botão mesmo. Agradeço a resposta Tobias.

Comment: @WSS fiz uma edição, acredito que vá lhe atender.

Comment: Coloquei esta implementação que fez, porém da um erro em cima do return: `Como "Clientes.BuscarClientes(int, Action<NpgsqlDataReader>)" retorna um void, uma palavra-chave return não dever ser seguida por uma expressão de objeto`, será que esqueci de algo?

Comment: @WSS desculpa, copiei do exemplo acima e esqueci de remover um trecho do código, tente agora.

Comment: Estou usando justamente o código do EDIT, é nele que mostra esta mensagem

Comment: Funcionou, retirei o return, já que é `void`, obrigado amigo! :D

Comment: @WSS eu fiz uma edição um pouco antes de postar o último comentário, então copie o código do EDIT novamente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67533/discussion-between-tobias-mesquita-and-wss).